# Mix of latin and greek script in source

Tags: unicode

I need to have a mix of latin and greek in the source, like "The angle is 2θ".
I tried to use LuaLatex with \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} but the greek characters are not rendered.

Modifying the text is not an option, for several reasons.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `alphabeta` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}

The angle is 2θ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use any characters that your font supports, if you switch to the modern toolchain.  Compile in LuaTeX or XeTeX, take out the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages, and load a font that supports Greek, such as `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` or `\usepackage{libertinus}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `unicode-math` and the [TeX Gyre fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/index_html).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}

The angle is 2θ in text.  The angle is $2θ$ in maths.  

\end{document}
```

Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, and (provided you have the TeX Gyre fonts available) you will get:

[image]